# Determinant calculator using cofactor

Tags: c, matrix, determinants

I'm trying to make a determinant calculator by using the cofactor method. Here is my code:

```
void det(int r,int c) {
    int check = 0;
    if(r==c) {
        check = 1;  
    } else check = 0;
    
    if(check) {
        int matrix[r][c], co[r-1][c-1];
        int i,j,k,t;
        int result = 0;
        int det = 0;
        
        printf("Enter your SQUARE matrix:\n");
        for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<c;j++) {
                scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        for(i=0;i<r;i++) {
            int p=i;
            for(j=0;j<c;j++) {
                int q=j;
                for(k=0;k<r;k++){
                    for(t=0;t<c;t++) {
                        if(k!=p && t!=q) {
                            co[k-1][t-1] = matrix[i][j];
                        }
                    }
                }
                int det = (co[0][0] * co[1][1]) - (co[0][1] * co[1][0]);
                result += (matrix[0][j] * pow(-1,(i+1)+(j+1))) * det;   
            }
        }
        
        printf("%d", result);
    }
                
}
```

- **co array** (the array stored cofactors)
- this is not the main function but if you want more information you can tell me.

I can't get the output right.
Here's my example matrix:

```
3x3
1 2 4
-1 2 2
5 1 3
```

I want the output to be:

```
-14
```

Comment: `co[k-1][t-1]` is out-of-range when `k==0` or `t==0` (fixing only this didn't gave me expected output)

Comment: It looks like even if your code worked, it could handle 3x3 and only 3x3 matrices. A co-factor approach needs to be recursive. That means recursive calls or equivalently a stack to keep track of the sub-matrices being worked on.

Comment: `pow()` is overkill to raise -1 to an integer power. (-1)^n is just `1 - 2 * (n & 1)`.

Comment: Minor: candidate `result += (matrix[0][j] * pow(-1,(i+1)+(j+1))) * det;` replacement: `result += matrix[0][j] * det * ((i^j)&1) ? -1 : 1;`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Likely faster to calculate directly than to use a branch. See my comment above yours.

Comment: With such [micro-optimizations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil), I've learned to trust the compiler.  IAC, we both agree to ditch `pow()`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to attempt to understand your code, since it has more nested for loops than are needed for this problem, and since it is not recursive and appears to have the potential to work only on 3x3 matrices.

This needs to be recursive. Or, equivalently, have a stack to keep track of the work. For an *n* by *n* matrix where *n* > 2, you break the problem into *n* pieces. There are *n* cofactor matrices built from all combinations of the *n* columns excluding the top element. Recursively compute the determinant of those. Then you can multiply each of those determinants by the top row value of the column that was omitted, and times 1, -1, 1, ... alternating in order for the top row elements, and add those up. That is your determinant. When *n* is 2, the determinant is the product of the diagonal elements minus the product of the off-diagonal elements. If you're given a 1x1 matrix, it's just the one element.

There are three nested for loops and a recursive call. Those are preceded by tests for *n* < 3, returning the appropriate value for those cases.

So something like this:

```c
int det(int n, int m[][n]) {
    if (n < 1)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return m[0][0];
    if (n == 2)
        return m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[0][1] * m[1][0];
    int d = 0, s = 1;
    int c[n - 1][n - 1];
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
                c[i][j] = m[i + 1][j < k ? j : j + 1];
        d += s * m[0][k] * det(n - 1, c);
        s = -s;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Or, a little more efficiently with only two levels of for loops, since only one column of the cofactor matrix needs to be replaced each time:

```c
int det(int n, int m[][n]) {
    if (n < 1)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return m[0][0];
    if (n == 2)
        return m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[0][1] * m[1][0];
    n--;
    int c[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            c[i][j] = m[i + 1][j + 1];
    int d = 0, s = 1, k = 0;
    for (;;) {
        d += s * m[0][k] * det(n, c);
        if (k == n)
            return d;
        s = -s;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            c[i][k] = m[i + 1][k];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Normally this would be done with `double`'s, not `int`'s, for the matrix elements.

Note that this is the worst possible way to compute a determinant when *n* gets large, since it will take O(*n*!) time. Far, far better is to reduce or decompose the matrix, which will take O(*n*<sup>3</sup>) time.

Comment: This assumes that your C compiler supports variable-length arrays, which apparently it does since your code uses them. Support for VLAs were required in C99, then optional in C11, and now will be required for function arguments but optional for allocations in C23. Go figure.

Comment: The `n == 2` case can be commented out, and the determinant will still be correct, ending the recursion at the `n == 1` case instead. The `n == 2` case is there to add a modicum of efficiency.